# CSS property is supported by element

Tags: html, css

Basically, I need to find out all HTML elements which support CSS properties 'background-color' and 'color' in **Chrome** browser. Ideally, all CSS properties related to colors which make a difference when cascaded and computed. I tried using [CSS.supports](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-conditional/#the-css-interface) method but it acts weird.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this something you're looking for?: http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/check-if-a-css-property-is-supported/

Answer (score 0):

All HTML elements supports these CSS properties:

```
var styleProperties = [
    'color',
    'backgroundColor'
];
var stylePropertiesLength = styleProperties.length;
var windowPropertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);
for (var i in windowPropertyNames) {
    if (windowPropertyNames.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var windowPropertyName = windowPropertyNames[i];        
        if (windowPropertyName.indexOf('HTML') === 0) {                             
            var documentElement = document.createElement(windowPropertyName);           
            for (var j = 0; j < stylePropertiesLength; j++) {
                var styleProperty = styleProperties[j];
                var isSupported = (styleProperty in documentElement.style);
                console.log(windowPropertyName + '.style.' + styleProperty + ' = ' + isSupported);  
            }                       
            console.log('');
        }
    }
}
```